# Choice design acc. to d-efficiency (Ngene): more than one block per respondent?

Tags: choice-modeling

I have a question with regard to choice design for discrete choice experiments.
Quite some time ago I conducted a choice experiment and now I am trying to publish a paper on that study. I got some helpful criticism and questions back from reviewers.
One question is difficult for me to answer because I am not much into the theory of choice design, and I don't have the original Ngene input/output anymore.

The choice design resulted first of all in 36 choice sets. We then used a foldover-command, as we wanted to explore interaction effects, so ended up with 72 choice sets. These choice sets were then blocked into 9 blocks of 8 choice sets each. However, we then ended up randomly assigning 2 blocks of 8 choice sets each to each of the respondents (instead of the usual approach of assigning only 1 block to each respondent).
The reviewer now asks me to discuss how this approach might affect design efficiency. 
I am probably naive, but I thought that assigning 2 blocks to each respondent should be similar to assigning 1 block to each respondent to twice as many respondents in total.

Can you maybe provide some information on how my approach might (negatively? or positively?) affect the design efficiency?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the "acc." in your title stand for?

Comment: It should stand for "according"